# Extract AD User information via ADSI

Tags: powershell, adsi

How can I get these properties for a user via ADSI LDAP, these are the properties from `Get-ADUser`, I need the equivalent for ADSI.

- Enabled
- PasswordNeverExpires
- PasswordExpired
- Name
- SamAccountName
- Mail
- PasswordLastSet

My objective is to query the entire domain for all users and get these attributes.

I tried with the `Get-ADUser` cmdlet and it timed out when querying for the users.

```psh
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties enabled,PasswordNeverExpires,passwordexpired,Name,SamAccountName,mail,passwordla‌​stset -server sc |
   where {$_.Enabled -eq "True"} |
   where { $_.PasswordNeverExpires -eq $false } |
   where { $_.passwordexpired -eq $false } |
   Select Name,SamAccountName,mail,
          @{l='PasswordExpires';e={$_.passwordlastset+(Get-ADDefa‌​ultDomainPasswordPolicy).MaxPasswordAge}},
          @{l='DaystoExpire';e={(New-TimeSpan -Start (get-date) -end ($_.passwordlastset+(Get-ADDefaultDomainPasswordPolicy).MaxPasswordAge)).days}}
```

The above command works on a couple of users but if I query a large set of users it gives invalid enumeration context.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The properties `SamAccountName`, `Name`, and `Mail` correspond to AD attributes of the same name. `PasswordLastSet` is derived from the attribute `pwdLastSet`. The other 3 properties (`Enabled`, `PasswordNeverExpires`, and `PasswordExpired`) are flags in the [`userAccountControl`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/305144) attribute.

Use an `adsisearcher` object with an LDAP query to search AD for user objects, then build custom objects with the desired properties:

```psh
$ACCOUNTDISABLE       = 0x000002
$DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWORD = 0x010000
$PASSWORD_EXPIRED     = 0x800000

$searcher = [adsisearcher]"(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person))"
$searcher.FindAll() | % {
  $user = [adsi]$_.Properties.adspath[0]
  New-Object -Type PSCustomObject -Property @{
    SamAccountName       = $user.sAMAccountName[0]
    Name                 = $user.name[0]
    Mail                 = $user.mail[0]
    PasswordLastSet      = [DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.Properties.pwdlastset[0])
    Enabled              = -not [bool]($user.userAccountControl[0] -band
                           $ACCOUNTDISABLE)
    PasswordNeverExpires = [bool]($user.userAccountControl[0] -band
                           $DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWORD)
    PasswordExpired      = [bool]($user.userAccountControl[0] -band
                           $PASSWORD_EXPIRED)
  }
}
```

With that said, why do you want to go to all this trouble instead of simply using `Get-ADUser` to the same end?

```psh
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$attributes = 'SamAccountName', 'Name', 'Mail', 'PasswordLastSet', 'Enabled',
              'PasswordNeverExpires', 'PasswordExpired'

Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties $attributes | select $attributes
```

Comment: Hi Ansgar, How can we get the same properties for a given list of specific users?

Comment: @SathishPanduga Please post a question of your own.

Comment: Hi Wiechers, here it is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38378434/how-to-get-ad-properties-for-a-list-of-windows-generic-accounts-in-powershell

Comment: The ADSI Method has the advantage to work without AD Module, including normal windows clients without ADDS Management tools.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Get-Item` over the `AD:\` Powershell drive, this cmdlet accepts the `-properties` argument to retrieve the designated list of properties. Using an asterisk causes the cmdlet to retrieve all properties. An example:

```
get-aduser -filter "sAMAccountName -like '*'" | % { get-item "AD:\$($_.distinguishedName)" -properties enabled,PasswordNeverExpires,passwordexpired,Name,SamAccountName,mail,passwordlastset }
```

EDIT: For calculated properties, including "Enabled", "Password never expires" etc, `Get-ADUser` can also accept `-properties` argument, so the code is just this:

```
get-aduser -filter "sAMAccountName -like '*'" -properties enabled,PasswordNeverExpires,passwordexpired,Name,SamAccountName,mail,passwordlastset
```

An asterisk also works fine.

Comment: i am actually getting this error "Get-ADUser : The server has returned the following error: invalid enumeration context." as i have more than 20k users to query

Comment: Pretty sure you at least need to provide a `-filter` for `Get-ADUser`

Comment: Get-Aduser -filter * -properties enabled,PasswordNeverExpires,passwordexpired,Name,SamAccountName,mail,passwordlastset -server sc  | where {$_.Enabled -eq "True"} | where { $_.PasswordNeverExpires -eq $false } | where { $_.passwordexpired -eq $false }  | Select Name,SamAccountName,mail,@{l='PasswordExpires';e={$_.passwordlastset+(Get-ADDefaultDomainPasswordPolicy).MaxPasswordAge}},@{l='DaystoExpire';e={(New-TimeSpan -Start (get-date) -end ($_.passwordlastset+(Get-ADDefaultDomainPasswordPolicy).MaxPasswordAge)).days}}

Comment: this is what i tried, it works on a couple of users but if i query a large set of users it gives invalid enumeration context

Comment: @PowerShell Weird, while there is about 5k users in here, there was no error and the default page size is 1000, less than both these values. Check updated post though.

Comment: @PowerShell You can use `-filter "PasswordNeverExpires -eq 'false' -and Enabled -eq 'True'"` as a filter to reduce the number of where-filtering at the very least. Also, you're calling `Get-ADDefa‌​ultDomainPasswordPolicy` once (EDIT: TWICE!) per user, you should cache this output prior to running such a query.

Comment: you rock!! @vesper this thing  "Get-Aduser -filter "PasswordNeverExpires -eq 'false' -and Enabled -eq 'True' -and passwordexpired -eq 'false'" -ResultPageSize 1000 -properties enabled,PasswordNeverExpires,passwordexpired,Name,SamAccountName,mail,passwordlastset -server sc  |  Select Name,SamAccountName,mail,@{l='PasswordExpires';e={$_.passwordlastset+$dpp}},@{l='DaystoExpire';e={(New-TimeSpan -Start (get-date) -end ($_.passwordlastset+$dpp)).days}}" ran in seconds :)

Comment: ok one more thing, how can i find ones with blank employee numbers ??

Comment: This depends on what is the attribute with "employee numbers". Is it plain `phone` or `otherTelephone`, or is it located elsewhere? You can query a single-valued attribute against `-ne ''`, with multivalued attributes it's a tad more difficult.

Comment: Hi Vesper, how can we get properties for a given list of specific users? (may be in a .txt file)

Comment: @SathishPanduga Load the txt into an array, and filter by `{$array -contains $user.samaccountname}`, should do.