# How to get AD properties for a list of windows generic accounts?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have below PowerShell commands, using which I can get the properties for all the users in the AD.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$attributes = 'SamAccountName', 'Name', 'Mail', 'PasswordLastSet', 'Enabled',
              'PasswordNeverExpires', 'PasswordExpired'
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties $attributes | select $attributes
```

If I want properties for one specific user, I can use below example in a command prompt:

```
net user /domain testuser
```

But, how can I get the AD properties for given list of users?

So, far I have tried the below but couldnt achieve yet as it returns only for one user (not sure how to loop):

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
cd AD:
$Users = gc "C:\AD\accounts.txt"
Get-ADUser -Filter '*' -Properties DisplayName, Office |
  ? { $Users -contains $_.SamAccountName } |
  select DisplayName, Office |
  Export-Csv -Path "C:\AD\output\UserProp_14072016.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

I'm looking for password last set, active or inactive, owner of that account.

Could you please help?

Comment: What do you mean by "active/inactive" and "owner"?

Comment: Active means, that the account is alive (user account is still valid and is being used).. and Owner means, the person who is the manager for that generic account.

Comment: The properties you're looking for are `Enabled` and `Manager`. Note that `Manager` is the distinguished name of the manager. You need to resolve that if you want the account or display name of that account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A technique I use for getting an arbitrary list of AD users is to construct an ORed LDAP filter from the text list:

```
$Users = gc "C:\AD\accounts.txt"

$User_filter = $Users -replace '^','(SamAccountName=' -replace '$',')'
$Filter = "(|$User_filter)"

Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter $Filter  -Properties DisplayName,Office
```

Comment: Hi @mjolinor, how can I add properties like IsActive and owner of the account in case of generic accounts?

Comment: You'll have to explain that request a little better. Those are not native properties of an AD object.  You'll have to add them yourself.  There are multiple ways to add properties to an object, and that's probably going to be better answered as a separate question.

Comment: Thanks a lot @mjolinor!

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$Users = "Get-Content C:\AD\Accounts.txt"
Get-ADUser -Filter '*' -Properties DisplayName,Office,PasswordLastSet,LastLogonDate | 
? {$Users -contains $_.SamAccountName} | 
Select DisplayName,Office,PasswordLastSet,LastLogonDate | 
Export-CSV -Path "C:\AD\output\UserProp_14072016.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

I'm not aware of a specific "Active" property, but you can add the "LastLogonDate" to the Properties to determine when the account was last logged onto.

Additionally, I'm not sure what  you're looking for when you are asking for the "Owner" of the account.

Incidentally, for a list of all of the properties available, you can do the following:

```
Get-ADUser <username> -Properties *
```

You may be able to find what you're looking for in the list.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot Robert, am checking it

Answer (score 1):

Get last logon on descending order

```
  Import-Module ActiveDirectory
    Get-ADUser -filter * -properties Displayname, LastLogonDate, SamAccountName, office, PasswordLastSet | select-object Displayname, LastLogonDate,office, SamAccountName, PasswordExpired, PasswordLastSet | Sort LastLogonTime -Descending  | Export-csv  c:\users.csv -NoTypeInformation
```